# Batch Script List Checking

Tags: list, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I'm working on a Windows 7 command line batch script to automate our build process.  Some of the projects that need to be built are dependent on other projects.  The normal process (assuming no dependencies) is to do a `dir /AD /B` from the repository root directory to get the names of the projects to compile.  (This works with the folder structure and naming convention we are using.)  What I'd like to do is add a file, buildorder.txt, to specify any necessary build order for dependencies *only*, which may or may not include all of the projects that need to be built.

Here is some pseudo code to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
if exist buildorder.txt (
  for /F %%i in buildorder.txt do (
    rem build each project in order specified in buildorder.txt
  )
)

for /F %%i in ('dir /AD /B') do (
  rem build all of the remaining project that have not already been built
)
```

Keep in mind, some (or perhaps all of the) items discovered for the second `for` loop will have already been processed in the first `for` loop, and I would rather not build those projects a second time.

Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: @rojo It works great! Please remember to post your answer and upvote my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second `for /F` loop, do

```
findstr /i "%%i" buildorder.txt >NUL || ( rem build %%i )
```

The [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) evaluates false and proceeds with the build if `%%i` is not found in `buildorder.txt`.